# Volume bezel faster fade or more transparent on OSX

Tags: macos

Many people are annoyed by the big fat bezels that appear on changing the volume/brightness/etc. and are pretty intrusive. Now, I'd like to still have them appear but make them less intrusive, e.g. by shortening the time until they fade away or making them more transparent. Anybody have an idea how to do one of the two?

[image]

Note, I'm aware of [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16849/how-do-i-disable-the-volume-control-overlay/212694#212694) that describes how to disable such overlay altogether, but that's not what I'd like to happen.

I'm using OSX El Capitan.