# Disable the "Connection lost" message when Bluetooth keyboard out of range

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, bluetooth, notifications

I have an Apple Bluetooth keyboard connected to my mid 2014 Macbook Pro. Sometimes I use the computer on my lap, in a room which is just on the threshold of connectivity. Every few minutes I get a message "Connection lost", then "Connected", popping up in the middle of the screen. Sometimes it happens so frequently it's actually hard to get work done because the middle of the screen is obscured so much.

Is there a way to disable this message? Turning off Bluetooth altogether is a bit disruptive. Everything works just as I'd expect it to - I just don't want the notification.

Comment: Have a look at this and see if it helps: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/212694/17536

Comment: Oh thanks. Disabling all bezel UIs is an interesting alternative approach!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by disabling the Bezel UI, here are instructions on how to do so from an answer from [another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/212694/17536) related to that:

> **To turn off bezels for this user until next login:**   `launchctl unload -F /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.BezelUI.plist`   To
>   undo, change `unload` to `load`, or just log out and back in.
>
> For macOS 10.12 Sierra: [Disable System Integrity
>   protection](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html),
>   then:   `launchctl unload -F
>   /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.OSDUIHelper.plist`   Don't
>   forget to enable System Integrity protection when you're done.
>
> ---
>
> **To turn off bezels indefinitely for this user:**   `launchctl unload -wF /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.BezelUI.plist`
>
> For macOS 10.12 Sierra: Disable System Integrity protection, then:
>   `launchctl unload -wF
>   /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.OSDUIHelper.plist`   You can
>   now enable System Integrity protection again -- your settings will
>   persist.
>
> To undo, change `unload` to `load`.
>
> ---
>
> **To turn off bezels indefinitely for all users:**   `sudo defaults write /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.BezelUI Disabled -bool
>   YES`
>
> For macOS 10.11 Sierra: [Disable System Integrity
>   protection](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html)
>   before doing the above.
>
> To undo, change `YES` to `NO`, or:   `sudo defaults delete
>   /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.BezelUI Disabled`
>
> For macOS 10.12 Sierra: [Disable System Integrity
>   protection](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html),
>   then:   `sudo defaults write
>   /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.OSDUIHelper Disabled -bool YES`
>   You can now enable System Integrity protection again -- your settings
>   will persist.
>
> To undo, change `YES` to `NO`, or:   `sudo defaults delete
>   /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.OSDUIHelper Disabled`
>
> Users can override this global setting using the two methods above.
>
> ---
>
> More info: `launchctl` is the command-line interface to [launchd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd), the
>   program that manages services and jobs on Mac OS.
>
> - To reverse any of the above actions, just change `unload` to `load`.
> - `-w` means **w**rite preference to disk so that it will be used for subsequent logins
> - `-F` means **f**orce un/load regardless of the global `Disabled` key
>
> You can read more about it in [`man launchctl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html).

Comment: It seems that the guidance for turning of bezels for all users indefinitely doesn't work on Mojave anymore. The guidance for a single user still works though.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the keyboard power before you walk away.

Comment: Having to do something manually every time is the kind of disruption I'm hoping to avoid.

Comment: You’re trading the adoption of one learnable habit for actual disruption to your productivity, but thank you for the feedback on my answer.

Comment: I think best case scenario is I would sometimes remember to turn the keyboard off, and sometimes remember to turn it back on. Meaning, in addition to the (less frequent) current problem, I'd also have the annoying problem of wondering why my keyboard wasn't working.