# Hide the brightness and volume bezels in Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina

In macOS Mojave I followed the instructions here to hide the brightness and volume overlays:

[Move the position of or hide the brightness/volume pop ups on high sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/320707/150109)

But this doesn't work anymore in Catalina:

```
$ csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.
$ sudo defaults write /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.OSDUIHelper Disabled -bool YES
2019-10-09 18:08:46.109 defaults[6792:141312] Could not write domain /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.OSDUIHelper; exiting
$ sudo defaults write /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.BezelUI Disabled -bool YES
2019-10-09 18:09:06.500 defaults[6824:141922] Could not write domain /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.BezelUI; exiting
```

How can I hide the brightness and volume overlays in macOS Catalina?

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/348538/51371) is still valid for a single user. The multiple users answer doesn't work on Mojave anymore as far as I can tell.

Comment: `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.BezelUI.plist: No such file or directory`