# How do I disable volume/brightness popup?

Tags: display, mojave, sound-volume

[image: popup]

This is the volume pop up. How do I remove it? It's highly annoying when it appears when playing a movie

Answer (score -1):

Like many things interface-y, there's a Terminal command for that. [Excellent explanation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16849/how-do-i-disable-the-volume-control-overlay) already exists.

Comment: It does not work

Comment: mm. Worked just fine for me. There were several options there. One was for temporarily disabling. Which option did you choose?

Comment: Also, the instructions have a link for disabling System Integrity Protection. If that applies to your OS (though the instructions say since 10.12, but really since 10.11), you have to do that first.