# disable brightness and volume change overlay mojave

Tags: macos, mojave

I followed [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/212694/150109) and (after disabling SIP) ran

```
sudo defaults write /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.OSDUIHelper\
  Disabled -bool YES
```

But it doesn't seem to have done anything, I still get the brightness pop up when I use the brightness keys to change screen brightness.

I am in macOS Mojave 10.14.4.

Comment: Well - the defaults should be reflected when you read, so if it does nothing, that’s the issue. If the preference is set, and you restart the mac and you can read the preference, then we have an entirely different question to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Two things could prevent the writing of the preference. If SIP isn’t verified to be disabled, that’s a blocker. Also, if you don’t see the preference set after a restart, there’s an issue with the defaults write command.

#### Is SIP disabled?

To be able to run that command you must first disable System Integrity Protection. That answer links to it here: [Configuring System Integrity Protection](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html).

If it's enabled you won't be able successfully run the `defaults write ...` command.

#### Example

```
$ csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: enabled.
```

You'll get a failure message like this:

```
$ sudo defaults write /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.OSDUIHelper \
     Disabled -bool YES
2019-04-19 16:53:21.310 defaults[92957:2162882] Could not write domain /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.OSDUIHelper; exiting
```

To disable/enable SIP:

> To enable or disable System Integrity Protection, you must boot to
>   Recovery OS and run the csrutil(1) command from the Terminal.
>
> 1. Boot to Recovery OS by restarting your machine and holding down the Command and R keys at startup.
> 2. Launch Terminal from the Utilities menu.
> 3. Enter the following command:
>
>    ```
>    $ csrutil enable
>    ```

#### But I have SIP disabled

If you've confirmed that SIP is disabled then you could use `opensnoop` to debug what's going on to gain additional insight as to why your `write` command is failing.

For example, in one terminal run this command to snoop:

```
$ sudo opensnoop -ve |& less
```

And in another window try running your `defaults write ...` command:

```
$ sudo defaults write /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.OSDUIHelper  Disabled -bool YES
2019-04-19 17:23:53.712 defaults[94310:2174907] Could not write domain /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.OSDUIHelper; exiting
```

Comment: I did disable it

Comment: @theonlygusti - can you update your Q to reflect that? Also was there any associated error message or output when you ran it?

Comment: no output when I run it

Comment: @theonlygusti see update, try debugging what's happening w/ `opensnoop`.

Comment: Harsh downvotes on an answer that is quite good IMO. Not sure what’s up, but +1 from me.

Comment: @bmike thanks, it's been going on a fair amount today DV's w/o any comment. Understand the deal but if there's something wrong a note lmk would be appreciated. Glad to fix something that's not right or to outright delete if it's off base.

Comment: It’s very educational and will help lots of people / get upvotes over time. Even if it’s wrong or doesn’t help OP, it’s helpful in the larger picture.

Comment: I don't understand the output of `opensnoop` but I don't think there are any errors, there's 777 lines of output from opensnoop and I'm not too sure which are relevant, but [here's a small sample](https://gist.github.com/theonlygusti/c1075e2dadc697abba41f40724a21c3c)