# Why does my volume adjust bezel not show properly in macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina, ui

I recently updated to macOS Catalina (10.15.3), and the "volume adjust" bezel that pops up in the center of my screen when I adjust the volume via touch bar no longer looks correct.  Specifically, it is missing the ticks that demarcate the volume level, instead just showing an empty bar.  Other similar bezels (e.g., display brightness) have the same issue.

I have already tried restarting, as well as [disabling the bezels entirely](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/212694/259483) and then re-enabling them.  Any other ideas how to fix this?

[image: Broken Volume Bezel]

Comment: It’s not an issue.  Developers are making changes to UI elements all the time and this would be one of those changes.  It’s not a problem, so there’s nothing to fix.  If you’re not happy with the change, it’s best to let Apple know.  https://www.apple.com/feedback/

Comment: @Allan Would that it were so, but on a different Mac running Catalina, the bezel UI displays as expected, so this is indeed a bug.

Comment: What precisely are you doing to disable there? (i.e. are your modifications causing this or perhaps making it harder to restore the default appearance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we're facing similar issues. There's no real fix, if you want to run with those settings, but at least you know what is going on.

If you're using the dark appearance (Settings -> General) and enable reduced transparency (Settings -> Accessibility -> Display) you end up in a situation like this.

Comment: Yup, this is it exactly.  Note that it is only determined by the "Reduced Transparency" setting - it is unrelated to dark mode (at least on my machine).

I would still call this a bug (why can't I have ticks without transparency?), but presumably Apple begs to differ...

Comment: I'm glad it sorted it out for you, it's definitively a bug. I've been using reduced transparency since I got my first Mac. This was just another issue in the train wreck named Catalina.